# Compare two DateTimeOffset objects

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I want to have the difference of two [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) object in days( for example check if the difference is less than 40 days).

I know it can be done by change it to FileTime, but wondering if there is any better way of doing it.

Comment: Just an fyi: the link you posted to the MSDN `DateTimeOffset` documentation has your answer written on the same page. Subtraction: `Subtracts one DateTimeOffset object from another and yields a time interval` and even includes a subtraction example at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way would be to subtract the offsets from eachother.  It returns a `TimeSpan` you can compare to.

```
var timespan = DateTimeOffset1 - DateTimeOffset2;
// timespan < TimeSpan.FromDays(40);
// timespan.Days < 40
```

I tend to prefer the ability to add it to another method passing in a TimeSpan, so then you're not limited to days or minutes, but just a span of time.  Something like:

```
bool IsLaterThan(DateTimeOffset first, DateTimeOffset second, TimeSpan diff){}
```

For fun, if you love fluent style code (I'm not a huge fan outside of it outside of  testing and configuration)

```
public static class TimeExtensions
{
    public static TimeSpan To(this DateTimeOffset first, DateTimeOffset second)
    { 
        return first - second;
    }

    public static bool IsShorterThan(this TimeSpan timeSpan, TimeSpan amount)
    {
        return timeSpan > amount;
    }

    public static bool IsLongerThan(this TimeSpan timeSpan, TimeSpan amount)
    {
        return timeSpan < amount;
    }
}
```

Would allow something like:

```
var startDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse("08/12/2012 12:00:00");
var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

if (startDate.To(now).IsShorterThan(TimeSpan.FromDays(40)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
}
```

Which reads something like "If the time from start date to now is shorter than 40 days".

Answer (score 4):

`DateTimeOffset` has a Subtract operator that returns a `TimeSpan`:

```
if((dto1 - dto2).Days < 40)
{
}
```